# ReactJS - как изменить состояние компонента не из компонента, а именно, state потомка изменить из родителя?

Tags: reactjs

Решения данной задачи, которые нахожу, либо не работают, либо слишком сложны для восприятия, поэтому обращаюсь сюда за советом. Вот в общих чертах:

```
class Cell extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {color: 'green'};
    }

    render() {
         return <div style={{background: this.state.color}}></div>;
    }
}

class Container extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.fillContainer = this.fillContainer.bind(this);
    }

    fillContainer() {
       var container = [];

       for (var i=0; i<666; i++) {
          var cell = <Cell/>;
          container.push(cell);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
           container.map((cell) => cell.setState({color: 'red'});
        }, 5000);

        return container;
     }

     render() {
         return (<div>{this.fillContainer()}</div>);
     }
}
```

Например, имеется компонент Container, в котором создается массив из компонентов Cell. У Cell имеется состояние state, которое определяет цвет ячейки и которое нужно изменить при проходе по массиву ячеек. И допустим, при этом ячеек очень много, state у каждой меняется очень часто и по длинному условию, и чтобы всё это не тормозило и не висло, у меня и возникло желание сделать это с помощью React и его способности реагировать на изменение state. Но state не доступен ниоткуда, кроме как из самого компонента, и функция, изменяющая state, например если добавить

```
this.setNewColor = this.setNewColor.bind(this);
setNewColor() {
    this.setState({color:'red'});
}
```

в Cell, тоже недоступна извне.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить state или хотя бы props компонента-потомка из компонента-родителя, или как сделать, чтобы функцию компонента можно было вызвать извне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте цвет через props

```
for (var i=0; i<666; i++) {
   container.push(
      <Cell
          key={i}
          color={someColor}
      />
   );
}


class Cell extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
         return <div style={{background: this.props.color}}></div>;
    }
}
```

или, если надо менять стейт компонента

```
class Cell extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            color: nextProps.color
        });
    }

    render() {
         return <div style={{background: this.state.color}}></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, конечно, это мне известно, что при создании элемента что угодно можно передать. Имелось в виду, как изменить состояние/свойства **уже созданного элемента**?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({color: nextProps.color});
}

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, но пока не могу понять, каким образом новые свойства nextProps попадают в функцию componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: Точнее, как задать новые свойства этому компоненту извне его?

Comment: Попадают, когда в render родителя отрисовывается Cell. Например, если массив цветов находится в state родителя, то изменение этого массива вызовет render родителя, где потомки "перерисуются", получая новые измененные props. В этот момент в потомках и произойдет событие componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: Спасибо! прояснилось.

Comment: Правда, пока я наблюдаю, что и без componentWillReceiveProps дочерние компоненты рендерятся заново (получив соответственно новые props), если сделать setState родителя. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В вашем примере с циклом. Дочерние компоненты не обновляются. Они перерисовываются заново при изменении родителя. Поэтому каждый раз хватают пропс